# javscript "." indent in web-mode

Tags: indentation, web-mode

In web-mode, the indentation after "."

```
var context = cubism.context()
                    .step(1e4)
                    .size(+d33.select("#using-cubism2")
                              .style("width")
                              .slice(0,-2));
```

I want to look like of js2-mode

```
var context = cubism.context()
    .step(1e4)
    .size(+d33.select("#using-cubism2")
          .style("width")
          .slice(0,-2));
```

Can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can find the variable 'web-mode-indenation-params' from the source code of web-mode. Then also can find the manual from the official site

```
You can disable arguments|concatenation|calls lineup with
(add-to-list 'web-mode-indentation-params '("lineup-args" . nil))
(add-to-list 'web-mode-indentation-params '("lineup-calls" . nil))
(add-to-list 'web-mode-indentation-params '("lineup-concats" . nil))
(add-to-list 'web-mode-indentation-params '("lineup-ternary" . nil))
```

Finally following solves my problem.

```
(add-to-list 'web-mode-indentation-params '("lineup-calls" . nil))
```

Comment: Mark your own answer as a solution if it solved your problem.